# Spring Boot Test doesnt load application context

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I created a application-integrationtest.yaml in my src/test/resources path so my test run against a created docker testcontainer. The problem is that my application-integrationtest.yaml is not being loaded.

I am running a SpringBoot 2.x application

This is my DataSource Class

```
@Configuration
public class IndexModificationDatabaseConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public JOOQToSpringExceptionTransformer 
  jooqToSpringExceptionTransformer() {
    return new JOOQToSpringExceptionTransformer();
  }

  @Bean
  public DataSourceConnectionProvider connectionProvider(final DataSource 
  dataSource) {
    return new DataSourceConnectionProvider(new 
    TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy(dataSource));
  }

  @Bean(name = "indexModification")
  @ConfigurationProperties("index-modified.datasource")
  public DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties() {
    return new DataSourceProperties();
  }

  @Bean
  public DataSource 
  indexModificationDataSource(@Qualifier("indexModification") final 
  DataSourceProperties properties) {
    return properties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
  }

  @Bean
  public DSLContext 
  createIndexModifiedDslContext(@Qualifier("indexModificationDataSource") 
  final DataSource dataSource) {
    final DefaultConfiguration configuration = new DefaultConfiguration();
    configuration.set(connectionProvider(dataSource));
    configuration.set(new 
    DefaultExecuteListenerProvider(jooqToSpringExceptionTransformer()));
    configuration.set(SQLDialect.POSTGRES);
    return new DefaultDSLContext(configuration);
  }
}
```

This is my Test

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {IndexModificationDatabaseConfiguration.class})
@ActiveProfiles("integrationtest")
public class ContainerOrchestrator {

  @Test
  public void testContainer() {
  assertTrue(true);
  }
}
```

And the exception is

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'indexModificationDataSource' threw exception; nested exception is 
 org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:582)
    ... 55 more
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

When i debug i see that my Datasource has null values on Driver, Url, password, etc.

Comment: What happens if you remove `(classes = {IndexModificationDatabaseConfiguration.class})` ? Are you sure everything is alrighty with your profile?

Comment: Ah now it works ! I thought í have to annotate the classes i want to inject, ty vm

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add @Profile annotation to your configuration class